# Issue with TreeRoute in PHP?

Tags: php, routes

I have a question in "Am I doing this right?", let me explain.. I included TreeRoute in my project and the example doesn't include how to call handlers attached to routes.

I had no option but to implement that part myself, I went ahead and tried and I hit a problem. All I have is the namespace to that file. Now 1 option is just put the file location in the route instead of the namespace but I don't think that would be good programming practice.

I've worked with frameworks such as Laravel where you just put a namespace and it includes the class for you, I've tried doing that here but all I have is the namespace, I guess my question is how do I include a class via its namespace, but then again am I doing this right? It feels wrong and dirty, If anyone can help clear this mess up it would be much appreciat

Routes.php:

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

$router = new \TreeRoute\Router();

$router->addRoute(['GET', 'POST'], '/', ['Phantom\Controllers\Frontend\Guest\LoginController', 'getView']);
```

Bootstrap.php:

```
require 'routes.php';

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$result = $router->dispatch($method, $url);

if (!isset($result['error'])) {
    $handler = $result['handler'];

    $class = $handler[0];
    include $class . '.php';
    $class = new $class;

    $method = $handler[1];

    $class->$method();
} 
else {
    switch ($result['error']['code']) {
        case 404 :
            echo 'Not found handler here...';
            break;
        case 405 :
            $allowedMethods = $result['allowed'];
            if ($method == 'OPTIONS') {
                echo 'OPTIONS method handler here...';
            }
            else {
                echo 'Method not allowed handler here...';
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If that namespace is in `$handler[0]` then you dont need, `include $class . '.php';` composer will autoload it.

Comment: $handler[0] is `Phantom\Controllers\Frontend\Guest\LoginController`, I've tried just including the namespace .php but it's failing to find it.

Comment: That namespace needs to have a psr-4 (check its been found in vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php), you could try `$class = '\'.$handler[0];` then `$class = new $class;` not `$class = new $handler[0];` Looking at the [source](https://github.com/baryshev/TreeRoute/blob/master/src/Router.php#L119) you should make use of all what `$result` returns else you wont be able to pass params.

Comment: the source is 200 lines, its not going to feature packed.

Comment: Thanks, the class I'm trying to 'include' isn't a composer package its a standalone PHP class, is it still a good idea to include my controllers directory in autload_psr4? I'm not familiar with the standard way of doing this.

Comment: If that class is standalone, you should definitely put the psr-4 in your root composer.json file and make use of the autoloader, else you will need to add your own autoloader.

Comment: I also suspect it relies on other things in its construct, and `Phantom\Controllers\Frontend\Guest\LoginController.php` is not going to work unless you have that folder structure. and `LoginController` class is in `Phantom\Controllers\Frontend\Guest` namespace.

Comment: When you say "you should definitely put the psr-r in your root composer.json file" are you still refering to putting it inside autoload_psr4? It seems like you've changed topic.

Comment: Yeah in your composer.json: https://3v4l.org/gFDGf